# tensorflw2.13.0 can't use gpu

Tags: tensorflow2.0

[this is the cuda in my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y9La.jpg)
[this is the cudatoolkit and cudnn in my conda venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EewQ8.jpg)
**when I import tensorflow :**

```
2023-12-20 11:10:24.331257: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:110] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-12-20 11:10:24.384137: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-12-20 11:10:25.153069: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
```

when I use **tf.test.is_gpu_available()**

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <stdin>:1: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2023-12-20 11:11:24.173168: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1960] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
False
```

What can be done to solve this problem?